# AppleScript shortcut for service not working, although clicking on application generated by Script Editor works fine

Tags: applescript, keyboard-shortcuts

I created an AppleScript for a sequence of copy-paste keystrokes and delays:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "k" using command down
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "a" using command down
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.1
    
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if it is running then
            quit
        else
            activate
            open location "http://translate.google.com"
            delay 1
            activate
            delay 0.7
        end if
    end tell
    
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 0.7
        keystroke "c" using control down
    end tell
end tell
```

I've exported it from Scripts Editor as an Application, and it works fine when I click on it.

When I try to execute it via a shortcut set at Systems Preferences > Keyboard > Shorcuts > Services, nothing happens; I just see the cog-wheel appearing briefly at the top bar. I already granted permission for the script-app at Systems Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility and already checked if there are hotkeys conflicts at the Terminal typing: `defaults find NSServicesStatus` or `defaults find '@~$]'` (the shortcut I've tried to use was Command+Alt+Shift+].

Would you maybe have any suggestion of where can I check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Those kinds of things tend to fail silently - you might try enclosing parts (or all) of the script in a `try` statement that displays a dialog.

Comment: NOTE: I don't understand what does keystroke "k" using  command down in your code. And what does keystroke "c" using control down. The last gets translated text to the clipboard in some application?

Comment: Also I've tried to run the code from inside the program menus, say Chrome > Services or Finder > Services - to no avail...

Comment: So, now it's clear. You are using an extension. I don't like them, because instead of controlling them, they control the user. Accordingly, I have little knowledge in dealing with their quirks.

Comment: Try to add "Google Chrome" to Accessibility to solve your problem with service.  As for the answer without using the extension, you should in the last handler move mouse pointer onto Copy button of Google Translate, delay 1, click button. using mouse tool like clicklic.

Comment: Why do you mean "extensions control the user"? would you have any example? Chrome was already added to accessibility... can you run your code in your Mac triggering it with keyboard shortcut? if so, how do you set it up in Automator, which parameters do you set?

Comment: You are now asking me to write the last handler and final service for you. When I have time, I will. Since it can be useful to me myself. Now I have to go to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reduce GUI scripting to have more stable code. Workaround is shown here:

```
my copyTextToClipboard()
set sourceText to (the clipboard) as string
my performGoogleTranslate(sourceText)
my getTranslatedTextToClipboard()

on copyTextToClipboard()
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "a" using command down
        delay 0.1
        keystroke "c" using command down
        delay 0.1
    end tell
end copyTextToClipboard

on performGoogleTranslate(sourceText)
    -- following translates from English (en) to Russian (ru)
    -- you can put other languadges settings
    set myURL to "https://translate.google.gr/?
    hl=el#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ru&text=" & sourceText
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        set URL of active tab of window 1 to myURL
    end tell
end performGoogleTranslate

on getTranslatedTextToClipboard()
    -- HERE you need some mouse tool to move the mouse pointer over
    -- the "Copy" button of Google Translate and to click it
end getTranslatedTextToClipboard
```

Comment: Thanks for optimizing the code, Robert. Cmd+K is a shortcut to get the text at the program, Ctrl+C is a hotkey provided to copy translated text to clipboard, this is provided by the extension "Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate" - but still, the code works only when clicked and not via keyboard... maybe anything else I should give permission?

Comment: RE: "HERE you need some mouse tool to move the mouse pointer over the "Copy" button of Google Translate and to click it" --- If the user has **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** checked from **Google Chrome** > **View** > **Developer**, then it probably would be much better to click the _button_ using **JavaScript** then "some mouse tool to move the mouse pointer". In testing, the page and translation must be finished loading, so a reasonable _delay_ of some manner needs to be added. In testing the following _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ worked to click the **Copy translation** _button_:

Comment: `tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe yHy1rc eT1oJ qiN4Vb itOtF IK3GNd')[0].click();"`

Comment: I like to use "Keyboard Shortcuts for Google Translate" extension - Ctrl+C copies the translated text.

Comment: Robert, I suspect there is something at my Automator Quick Action parameters preventing it to run properly; would you kindly share how should I set up the script there?

Comment: I've managed to run with a keyboard shorcut! On Automator, I was forgetting to select Library > Utilities > Run AppleScript ‍♂️ thank you so much for all your attention!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option which takes a completely different route, without having to resort to using UI scripting and without having to open any browsers.

To be able to use my solution, you'll have to install the  [translate-shell](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/) shell command.  In **Terminal.app**, I installed it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with this command… `brew install translate-shell`

After successful installation of the [translate-shell](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/) shell command, [it can then be used in **AppleScripts** and **Automator Workflows**](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/wiki/AppleScript)

This following **AppleScript** code will take the text, which is currently on your clipboard, and translate it to the language of your choice.  It will then set the content of your clipboard to the translated text.

I took the liberty to add a few [Language Codes](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/wiki/Languages) to get you started.

```
property convertLanguage : {"Convert To Belarusian (be)", "Convert To Bulgarian (bg)", ¬
    "Convert To Dutch (nl)", "Convert To English (en)", "Convert To Estonian (et)", ¬
    "Convert To French (fr)", "Convert To German (de)", "Convert To Greek (el)", ¬
    "Convert To Hebrew (he)", "Convert To Hungarian (hu)", "Convert To Italian (it)", ¬
    "Convert To Polish (pl)", "Convert To Romanian (ro)", "Convert To Russian (ru)", ¬
    "Convert To Spanish (es)", "Convert To Swedish (sv)", "Convert To Ukrainian (uk)"}

activate
set chosenLanguage to word 4 of ((choose from list convertLanguage ¬
    with title "Language Translator" with prompt ¬
    "Choose A Language To Convert To" OK button name ¬
    "Translate" cancel button name "Cancel") as text)

convertToLanguage(chosenLanguage)

on convertToLanguage(twoLetterLanguageCode)
    set textToConvert to the clipboard
    delay 0.1
    set the clipboard to ¬
        (do shell script "export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:$PATH\";/usr/local/bin/trans -b :" & ¬
            quoted form of twoLetterLanguageCode & " " & ¬
            quoted form of (textToConvert as text))
end convertToLanguage
```

---

This following animation demonstrates the conversion of the English text (already on my clipboard) to French. Then I paste the converted text into the document.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I didn't know there was still a free translation tool with Google Translate. An upvote for your answer.

Comment: Bravo! that's an elegant solution.